# Docker error "exec format error" in reverse proxy of nginx

Tags: pi-4, docker

## Short Version

I am trying to rebuild the reverse proxy of [`jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) on my Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian 10.

As the container is not configured for `armhf` architectures, I tweaked the `Dockerfile` using the [`arm32v7/nginx:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/nginx/) container.
I am able to build the container, but it returns the error `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"` when I run it.

Googling around let me assume that some part of the process load a binary that wasn't built for the armhf architecture. But I am not able pinpoint the error or fix it.

I also tried to replicate the steps in an interactive session `docker run -it --rm arm32v7/nginx:latest bash` (specifically, I was able to get [`docker-gen`](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen) and [`forego`](https://github.com/ddollar/forego) to run and print their versions (0.7.4 and dev)) and wasn't able to replicate the issue, i.e., the individual steps seem to work and didn't throw the error.

Any idea what causes the error and how to fix it?

### Dockerfile

Most of this is copied from the [original Dockerfile of `jwilder/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/Dockerfile) with a different base nginx container, as well as some minor tweaks to installing docker-gen and forego, and copying the `uploadsize.conf` from the nextcloud example (see below).

All changes are commented with a `#>`!

Note I also have the respective files

- [`uploadsize.conf`](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy/postgres/apache/proxy/uploadsize.conf)
- [`network_internal.conf`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/network_internal.conf)
- [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh)

at the same path as the Dockerfile.

```
# Replicating jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
#> Changed to the right architecture for the pi 4
FROM arm32v7/nginx:latest

# Install wget and install/updates certificates
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    wget \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure Nginx and apply fix for very long server names
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
 && sed -i 's/worker_processes  1/worker_processes  auto/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Install Forego
#> Changed forego install process to an armhf architecture
RUN wget -q https://github.com/djmaze/armhf-forego/releases/download/v0.16.1/forego -O /usr/local/bin/forego
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/forego

# Install docker-gen
#> Changed Version number and platform to the newest and armhf version
ENV DOCKER_GEN_VERSION 0.7.4
ENV DOCKER_PLATFORM armhf 

RUN wget -q -O - https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen/releases/download/$DOCKER_GEN_VERSION/docker-gen-linux-$DOCKER_PLATFORM-$DOCKER_GEN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  | tar -C /usr/local/bin -xvz

COPY network_internal.conf /etc/nginx/

#> included from the nextcloud example
COPY uploadsize.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/uploadsize.conf  

COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/

ENV DOCKER_HOST unix:///tmp/docker.sock

VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/dhparam"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["forego", "start", "-r"]
```

### Commands

```
docker build -t reverse-proxy . # works as expected
docker run reverse-proxy        # fails with the error
> standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

## Avoiding the [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309783)

The ultimate goal is to use docker to run nextcloud and pihole on my raspberry pi. The reverse proxy is used by [nextcloud's examples](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy/postgres/apache) to hide the different service (postgres, nextcloud, etc) behind the reverse proxy.

If you know any way to do this without the reverse proxy, I'd be happy to listen. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have the same issue and tried this https://github.com/Alexander-Krause/rpi-docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion. But also didnt worked. Did you solved it?

Comment: In the end I didnt use nexcloud in a docker container but installed it directly. So I didn't solve this specific issue, but the underlying problem got solved.

Answer (score 2):

Woah, I know it's already been a year since there has been any activity here, but for everyone else having this issue while trying to set up jwilder/nginx-proxy using Docker on their Raspberry Pi (or any other device with an ARM based processor):

A super cool dude called "Brain Gamer" has created a [fork](https://github.com/Brain-Gamer/nginx-proxy) for creating working armhf builds of the [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy).

https://hub.docker.com/r/braingamer/nginx-proxy-arm/